# I don't understand why the following code doesn't place the circle exactly in the image center

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I don't understand why to following code don't place the circle exactly in the image center.

```
let face = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myFace", for: indexPath) as! Face
print("face cellForItemAt \(indexPath) and frame \(face.frame)")

face.tag = indexPath.row
let _ = face.contentView.subviews.map({$0.removeFromSuperview})
let ind = indexPath.row
let vi = UIImageView()
vi.frame = face.contentView.frame
vi.image = UIImage(cgImage: panim[ind])

let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.frame = vi.frame
let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: vi.frame)
circle.append(UIBezierPath(rect: vi.frame))
circle.usesEvenOddFillRule = false
layer.path = circle.cgPath
layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor
layer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
layer.fillRule =  kCAFillRuleNonZero
vi.layer.addSublayer(layer)

face.contentView.addSubview(vi)
return face
```

[image: Horizontal UICollectionView spanning on one line. Each cell is a face]

Comment: Coordinate systems can get somewhat weird. Can you check to see if the child layer is being placed correctly in vi? Maybe try changing the code dealing with the circle to use `layer.frame` instead of `vi.frame`

Comment: Tried. Did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're offsetting the path twice: once in the path itself and once in the shape layer's frame. You probably want neither.

The shape layer's path is relative to the coordinate system of the shape layer and in turn, the shape layer's frame is relative to the coordinate system of its super layer (the image view's layer).

For both of these you're specifying the image view's frame, a value which has some offset to its super view; the cell's content view.

This means two things for your code:

Since the shape layer's frame is relative to its super layer (the image view's layer), if you want the shape layer to be positioned in the upper left corner of the image view, then you should set the shape layer's frame to the image view's *bounds* (or just a rectangle with a zero origin and the same size as the image view).

```
layer.frame = vi.bounds
```

Since the shape layer's path is relative to the shape layer, if you want to draw a circle that fills the shape layer then your path should be an oval in the shape layer's *bounds*.

```
let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: layer.bounds)
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked perfectly . Many Thanks